# Python MySQLdb: Inserting duplicate entry into a table with UNIQUE fields

Tags: python, mysql, duplicates, mysql-python

I have a MySQL database that contains a table named `commands` with the following structure:

```
+-----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| input     | varchar(3000) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| inputhash | varchar(66)   | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
+-----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I am trying to insert rows in it, but only if the `inputhash` field does not already exist. I thought `INSERT IGNORE` was the way to do this, but I am still getting warnings.

For instance, suppose that the able already contains

```
+----+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | input   | inputhash                                                        |
+----+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | enable  | 234a86bf393cadeba1bcbc09a244a398ac10c23a51e7fd72d7c449ef0edaa9e9 |
+----+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Then when using the following Python code to insert a row

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', user='xxxx', passwd='xxxx', db='dbase')
c = db.cursor()
c.execute('INSERT IGNORE INTO `commands` (`input`, `inputhash`) VALUES (%s, %s)', ('enable', '234a86bf393cadeba1bcbc09a244a398ac10c23a51e7fd72d7c449ef0edaa9e9',))
```

I am getting the warning

```
Warning: Duplicate entry '234a86bf393cadeba1bcbc09a244a398ac10c23a51e7fd72d7c449ef0edaa9e9' for key 'inputhash'
  c.execute('INSERT IGNORE INTO `commands` (`input`, `inputhash`) VALUES (%s, %s)', ('enable','234a86bf393cadeba1bcbc09a244a398ac10c23a51e7fd72d7c449ef0edaa9e9',))
```

Why does this happen? I thought that the whole point of using `INSERT IGNORE` on a table with `UNIQUE` fields is to suppress the error and simply ignore the write attempt?

What is the proper way to resolve this? I suppose I can suppress the warning in Python with `warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')` but why does the warning appear in the first place?

Comment: If you use the IGNORE modifier, errors that occur while executing the INSERT statement are ignored. For example, without IGNORE, a row that duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With IGNORE, the row is discarded and no error occurs. Ignored errors generate warnings instead. (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) pay special attention to  "Ignored errors generate warnings instead."

Comment: So, the only "clean" way (no errors, no warnings) to avoid storing duplicate data in the database is by turning off the warnings?! I can't check if the value already exists because of race conditions (somebody might write the same value as me after I've determined that it doesn't exist but before I've written mine). I tried locking the table but that didn't work, either.

Answer (score -1):

**I hope it will help you !**

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', user='xxxx', passwd='xxxx', 
db='dbase')
c = db.cursor()
c.execute('INSERT INTO `commands` (`input`, `inputhash`) VALUES ('enable', 
'234a86bf393cadeba1bcbc09a244a398ac10c23a51e7fd72d7c449ef0edaa9e9') ON 
DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 'inputhash'='inputhash')
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is normally used to force a write operation when it wouldn't normally occur, because of a `UNIQUE` field. In addition, in my case I have an auto-incremented field, so wouldn't this just result in duplicated lines? I don't want duplicated lines; I _want_ the duplicated info to be ignored. I just don't want to get warnings when it is.